# sqlplus hangs after being called from a batch file, without throwing up error message

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, connection, sqlplus

Essentially, where I work we run a variety of reporting processes that follow the same basic structure...

A batch file calls an sql script which executes a stored procedure. Another script extracts the data from Oracle and writes to a csv. Finally, an excel macro runs to create the final output.

We have been encountering an issue recently where if the procedure takes approximately longer than an hour to run, it will then hang indefinitely without moving on to the next line of the batch file. No error message is thrown up.

The most frustrating part is that certain procedures sometimes have the issue, and then the next day they do not.

Has anyone else ever encountered this issue? Or have any idea what could be causing this problem? I feel like it could be connection/firewall related, but it really is not my area of expertise!

Comment: This sounds like a performance tuning issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instrument the batch file and use extended SQL tracing to reveal where ALL of your time is going. Nothing can escape proper instrumentation. You will find the source of the problem. What you do about it varies depending upon the particular problem (i.e., anti-pattern).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was will have a read up on this and test a couple of the problem processes.

Answer (score 0):

I see issues like this all the time.  What I do it to connect to the DB and see what is running by checking gV$session.  Key is to identify what SQL the script is running, then see if there are any reasons for it to be "hung" (there are MANY possible reasons).  for example, missing indexes ; missing or not up to date stats ; workload on the instance ; blocking locks ; ...
If you have the SQL Tuning Advisor, you can run the SQL through there to get some ideas on solutions.  Also ADDM Report may provide some additional solutions.